# Why Tomcat use much memory?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory

i have a server with tomcat with some webapps in.
If i do free -h i view about 50% used:
With TOP:
i view that this process:

```
 21603 azureus+  20   0 7816556 1.104g  18200 S   0.0  45.1   0:36.41 


    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config
.file=/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.loggi
ng.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.
protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.Secu
rityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-t
omcat-9.0.8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/bin/tomcat-juli.j
ar -Dcatalina.base=/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8 -Dcatalina.home=/home/azureu
ser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Use 45% of memory.

i want undstand if is a problem of my code in some projects or is a problem of TOMCAT.

Some Tips?
Thanks all

Comment: Try to use [Visual VM](https://visualvm.github.io/documentation.html) to find out what kind of object use most of the memory first.

Comment: but i'm on unix server

Comment: You can execute the visualvm binary (without .exe) in the downloaded zip.

Comment: no.. i have a remote serve unix but i'm on windows

Comment: There is a section "Working with Remote Applications" in the document, you may need some time to read if you did not try VisualVM before.

Comment: I  have installed VisualVM but i dont install or control if jstatd is running on remote.. if i do jstadt on remote i have this error: Could not create remote object
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")